# Android Azure Mobile Services Offline Sync Background Async

Tags: android, azure, android-asynctask, socket-timeout-exception

I've got an Android App connected to Azure using Azure Mobile Services. I have implemented offline sync and have created a background async process to sync the data between app and cloud every 15 minutes.

I press the power/sleep button and it works for the first hour or so but after I get an error from the sync process:

```
11-20 13:09:22.537 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Error while processing request.
11-20 13:09:22.547 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
11-20 13:09:22.557 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
11-20 13:09:22.557 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
11-20 13:09:22.557 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.mycompany.myapp.DatabaseAccess$2.doInBackground(DatabaseAccess.java:1195)
11-20 13:09:22.557 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.mycompany.myapp.DatabaseAccess$2.doInBackground(DatabaseAccess.java:1186)
11-20 13:09:22.557 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
11-20 13:09:22.557 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-20 13:09:22.557 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-20 13:09:22.557 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-20 13:09:22.557 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err: Caused by: com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Error while processing request.
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:138)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$15.handleRequest(MobileServiceClient.java:1610)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection.start(MobileServiceConnection.java:113)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:78)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:35)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:  ... 5 more
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to myappapp.azurewebsites.net/[IP ADDRESS] (port 443) after 120000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:238)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
11-20 13:09:22.567 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$Android.connectSocket(Platform.java:190)
11-20 13:09:22.577 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196)
11-20 13:09:22.577 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
11-20 13:09:22.577 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
11-20 13:09:22.577 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
11-20 13:09:22.577 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
11-20 13:09:22.577 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
11-20 13:09:22.587 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
11-20 13:09:22.587 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
11-20 13:09:22.587 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
11-20 13:09:22.587 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
11-20 13:09:22.587 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilterRequestImpl.execute(ServiceFilterRequestImpl.java:164)
11-20 13:09:22.587 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:121)
11-20 13:09:22.587 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:  ... 9 more
11-20 13:09:22.587 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
11-20 13:09:22.587 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
11-20 13:09:22.597 2522-3106/com.mycompany.myapp W/System.err:  ... 27 more
```

Any ideas on why its happening and how to fix it? I'm using a Samsung Tablet as my test device.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Refresh Tokens
>
> The token returned by Azure App Service Authentication and Authorization has a
>   defined life time of one hour. After this period, you must reauthenticate the user. 
>       [How to use the Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library)

Your authentication token needs to be be refreshed after 1 hour. You can achieve this by calling .login() or .refreshUser() methods. Please post your code if you manage to do this successfully.